# How to run code when the home button is held down? (Android)

Tags: java, android, service

How can I have some code be run when the user holds down the home button (or back button) when they are **outside of the app**?

I have a virtual assistant application and I want it to start running when the user holds down the home button. Can I do it with this code?

```
public class HomeHoldDown extends ActionBarActivity
{
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Key pressed long!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry you can not detect home button event because of security reason.

Comment: I suppose you want to make a service to run code in the background and the closest you can get to detecting home button would be OnPause and OnStop which will catch when your application goes out of view.

Comment: @CodeCamper Sorry, but how would you do that?

Comment: @SnowboardingProgrammer Just override the OnPause and OnStop method to do whatever you want but once your app is gone from visibility that thread will be frozen till it pops up again. That is why you need [Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) if you want to draw over other apps the only way I know to do that right now is with [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531)

Comment: Thanks @CodeCamper but I dont want that type of thing. How do other apps do it like Utter! and Google Now?

Comment: @SnowboardingProgrammer What do they do?

Comment: @CodeCamper They run in the background and detect when the user holds down the home button, then starts running. They are both virtual assistants like what I'm trying to make.

Comment: @SnowboardingProgrammer My Google Now is a seperate button in the home button screen, yours automatically opens?

Comment: @CodeCamper what about Utter? that one does it when you hold down the home button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50935/discussion-between-snowboardingprogrammer-and-codecamper)